# CodeIgniter field validation based on condition

Tags: codeigniter, validation, conditional-statements

If the first field called `sendEmail` has `value ="Yes"` the rest of the fields are to be validated...
I have this `set_rules` defined in the `form_validation.php` file in the config folder..

```
$config = array(
array(
      'field'   => 'sendEmail',
      'label'   => 'Send Email',
      'rules'   => 'required'
     ),
     array(
       'field'   => 'email',
       'label'   => 'Email',
       'rules'   => 'required'
     ),
     array(
       'field'   => 'first_name',
       'label'   => 'First Name',
       'rules'   => 'required'
     ),   
    array(
      'field'   => 'last_name',
      'label'   => 'Last Name',
      'rules'   => 'required'
    )
);
```

but `email`, `first_name` and `last_name` fields are to be validated only `if` `sendEmail` has `value="Yes"`.
Not sure how to do this, can someone please help me with this?
thanks

Answer (score 6):

Do the conditions like this in your controller:

```
if ($this->input->post('sendEmail') == 'Yes'){

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
  ... [etc]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The validation only runs when you call `$this->form_validation->run()`, so just write an if statement before that. Something like this:

```
if ($this->input->post("sendEmail") == 'Yes') {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // failed validated
    }
    else
    {
        // passed validation
    }
} else {
    // never attempted validation
}
```